# Adding characters conditionally to a regular expression match

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I am using regular expressions in Eclipse, and was wondering whether there's a way to add characters based on the matches.

I am using these expressions to match and replace:

```
Match: ^(\s*)(//)?(.*?)"([\p{Punct}\p{Space}]*)?(\p{Alnum}.*?\p{Alnum})([\p{Punct}\p{Space}]*)?"(.*?)$
Replace: $1$3"$4" \+ i18n.tr\("$5"\) \+ "$6"$7
```

For example

```
System.err.println("Unexpected number of guests: ");
```

I am trying to replace this with

```
System.err.println(i18n.tr("Unexpected number of guests") + ": ");
```

But I am getting

```
System.err.println("" + i18n.tr("Unexpected number of guests") + ": ");
```

Is there any way to get rid of the "" + preceding i18n.tr(.*) if there's nothing captured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a single search-replace!

The only way is to use two search-replace:

- the first with the punct-space

`Match: ^(\s*)(//)?(.*?)"([\p{Punct}\p{Space}]++)(\p{Alnum}.*?\p{Alnum})([\p{Punct}\p{Space}]*)?"(.*?)$`

`Replace: $1$3"$4" \+ i18n.tr\("$5"\) \+ "$6"$7`

- second without the punct-space

`Match: ^(\s*)(//)?(.*?)"(\p{Alnum}.*?\p{Alnum})([\p{Punct}\p{Space}]*)?"(.*?)$`

`Replace: $1$3i18n.tr\("$4"\) \+ "$5"$6`

Don't forget to do a backup before any tries

Comment: Ah, cool, thanks. I ended up using ( \+ ""|"" \+ ) to replace with a blank on my second pass. Was a bit more effort, but I didn't have too many statements that matched besides the ones I created.